# Nested Json using Gson returning a null value

Tags: java, json, gson

The project I am working on is trying to communicate with the FDA API and retrieve certain information. However, with my nested JSON, the object I am trying to retrieve is returning a `null` value. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thank you and please let me know if I am missing any information.

URL I am trying to access information from:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?

**JSON Tester Class**

```
package com.example.user.searchbarapp;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class JSONTester {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        URL FDAServer = new URL("https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
        FDAServer.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        Medication advil = g.fromJson(inputStream, Medication.class);
        System.out.print(advil);
    }
}
```

**Medication Class**

```
package com.example.user.searchbarapp;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Medication {

    private NestedMedication[] NestedMedication;

    public Medication(com.example.user.searchbarapp.NestedMedication[] nestedMedication) {
        NestedMedication = nestedMedication;
    }

    public com.example.user.searchbarapp.NestedMedication[] getNestedMedication() {
        return NestedMedication;
    }

    public void setNestedMedication(com.example.user.searchbarapp.NestedMedication[] nestedMedication) {
        NestedMedication = nestedMedication;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Medication{" +
                "NestedMedication=" + Arrays.toString(NestedMedication) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**NestedMedication Class**

```
package com.example.user.searchbarapp;

public class NestedMedication {

    String route;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NestedMedication{" +
                "route='" + route + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Medication{NestedMedication=null}
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The json you linked doesn't have a `NestedMedication` node. Did you mean `results`?

Comment: Do I need to name my classes after the nodes of the json I am trying to access? I thought if I defined route in the NestedMedication that it would access it